# Navigation properties in separate class

Tags: entity-framework

I have a **User** model with navigation properties for city, town and district tables:

```
public class User
{
    ...
    public virtual Location_City City { get; set; }
    public virtual Location_Town Town { get; set; }
    public virtual Location_District District { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to group these properties in a separate class and re-use that class instead, as shown below:

```
public class Location
{
    public virtual Location_City City { get; set; }
    public virtual Location_Town Town { get; set; }
    public virtual Location_District District { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    ...
    public Location Location { get; set; }
    public Location ContactPersonLocation {get; set;}
}
```

I tried various combinations where I removed **virtual** from **Location** class and set Location properties of **User** class as navigation properties instead, but I am getting the following error:

`EntityType 'Location' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Locations: EntityType: EntitySet 'Locations' is based on type 'Location' that has no keys defined.`

Is it possible to have navigation properties in a separate class or do I need to create a separate table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to create separate table for Location, then you should use [Complex Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738472.aspx) (they don't have key and stored in same table as entity which have complex type property). But here is another problem - as documentation says:

> Complex type cannot contain navigation properties.

So, answer is obvious - you should create separate junction table for keeping Location. And Location should be entity with key.

Comment: Thanks, I did create a junction table :)